# Como importo corretamente utilizando Maven no Android Studio?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Importei a `org.apache.commons:commons-email` através do comando `ALT + SHIFT + CTRL + S` no Android Studio. A classe identificou sem problemas porém não consigo compilar o projeto!PS: Entrei no diretório do erro e só possui um arquivo `activation-1.1.1.jar`

> 21:30:01 Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 34 sec 
>   Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK
>   /home/daniela/AndroidStudioProjects/ConectaSP/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt      File 1: /home/daniela/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar
> >       File 2:
> >     /home/daniela/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar

[image: Importação de dependência no Maven]

Comment: Se não me engano você teria que incluir o `packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' }` no seu **gradle.build** do seu módulo principal para excluir o arquivo duplicado.